# Dissimilar movement between parent and child in BGE

Tags: game-engine, physics, parent

In this [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38439) I have the following problem.

- Every time I rotate the "Player" the camera rotates in a radius way huger than it should. Check the "Plane" to verify this or through the camera view.

It used to work fine till I appended the object "Flashlight", which is a child of the "Flashlight_empty". Also when I appended it, it spawned as "Flashlight.001" while I have/had no other object with the same name. I changed it back to "Flashlight". I think it has something to do with the physics boxes, cause when collision box option is deactivated the player has a sphere around it(maybe it is a default thing) while when I activate it goes with the box. I played with it and might have messed it. Anyways it might be something simpler also.

Comment: There is no need to upload a 3MB file. It would be better to provide a very small file that focus on the problem.  I can't see that something rotates = I can't see any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem description indicates you have a non-uniform scale on one or more parents. According to your file the problem is the "Player" object.

Solution:

Ensure the scale is set to (1.0, 1.0, 1.0).
You can do this by pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> *> Scale*.

Comment: That was it, but how could I possibly have scaled it and then remain visually scaled but not in the numbers?

Comment: You scaled the object, rather than the mesh. Be aware object scaling gets inherited by the children (objects too). This has impact on the space the child is living in. If that space is inhomogene scaled, an rotation would result in an ellipse rather than a circle.